# UWP App with Azure AD Authentication - how to tell the signed in state of a user

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-active-directory

I have built a small UWP app in C# that contains Azure AD authentication (to our corporate Azure AD account) based off the sample found here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-wam/tree/master/NativeClient-UWP-WAM

I have the sample working successfully in my app, but I can't find a way to detect that a user is or isn't signed in (after the sign in is complete). I want to use this to ensure users can't navigate to other pages in the UWP app without being authenticated. If I was doing this in ASP.NET I would check something like the Context.Identity.User object.  I just want to be able to do (in pseudo code)

Navigate to Page 1
if user signedIn = true, show page. If false, error/fail.

I've looked up user state, signed in state etc, but nothing really shows up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable the User Account Information in the package.appmanifest
   [image]
2. Then try:

   ```
   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();

       var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus ==                                
       UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated && 
                           p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

       // user may have username
       var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
       string displayName = (string)data;

       text1.Text = displayName; 
   }
   ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.User

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try this out and see how I go. I really appreciate you finding the time to answer.

Comment: @JamesMatson How about this issue now? Was your issue resolved?

Comment: Hi Lui, I haven't actually progressed this. After reviewing the functionality of PowerApps I found it to be highly suitable for this use case, so am porting the app to PowerApps. This provides me the ability to quickly develop a good presentation UI (and user sign in is a non issue as the App can derive the user straight from User() ) without the complexity of UWP/XAML. I will progress this at some point, but PowerApps backed by some good web APIs will do the trick faster and more seamless than a XAML based UWP app. Thank you though. When I finally test this I will mark the answer